# Insert Foreign key values into a table from a related table set (1-M)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for the `query` that will allow me to perform the following:

I have two tables **Page** and **Section** with `1-M relation` (Each page has only one section, and each section can have multiple pages)

I need to Insert into the table **Page** some default values,one of the values is calling the MAX() function on the Page Table and finally all section_IDs are retrieved from a SQL statment.

When i test the query using one existing Section ID , it works fine.
The query is as follow :

```
Insert into page(.....page_order,section_id,.....)
SELECT
.
.
MAX(page_order)+1,
1111,
.
.
from Section where section_id= 1111
```

Now, here the query to get all the Section IDs i need:

```
select section_id from Section where section_name = 'ABC'
```

Now how to replace my 1111 with the list i got from the second query .
I tried this:

```
Insert intov page(.......,section_id,.....)
SELECT
.
.
.
(   select section_id from Section where section_name = 'ABC'),
.
.
from Section where section_id= (   select section_id from Section where section_name = 'ABC')
```

but didnt work

EDIT2:

I tried this :

```
    INSERT INTO page(page_order, section_id)
SELECT 
   max(page.page_order)+1,
   section.section_id 
FROM 
   section,page
WHERE 
  section_name = 'ABC' 
GROUP BY 
   section.section_id
```

But it doesn't calculate the MAX() correctly , i need the max of the subset of Sections with the same PageID.
It returns the max in all page order + 1

Comment: why would this work for you Insert into page(.......,section_id,.....) select * from Section where section_name = 'ABC'

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO page(page_order, section_id)
SELECT 
   max(page_order)+1,
   section_id 
FROM 
   section 
   LEFT JOIN page
   ON section.section_id = page.section_id
WHERE 
  section_name = 'ABC' 
GROUP BY 
   section_id
```

Comment: Check my edits, i am now having a problem with the max field: error message:  `The multi-part identifier "page_order" could not be bound.`

Comment: even after adding the group by , i got the same error message: Page_order could not be bound

Comment: I see -- it's coming out of a different table, and you need to join the tables as well.

Comment: That's right , i just added the join condition and it works fine now. you can edit your answer to include the join statement and i will accept it as an answer